# Check admin privileges on cross-domain workstation C#

Tags: search, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to check if a user is an admin on a particular machine.
I have the following code that works fine when the computer is on the same domain:

```
public bool CheckAdmins(string computerName)
{
    var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    string branchnumber = computerName.Substring(0, 3);

    bool admin = false;

    if (logonUser.authenticate())
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry machine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + logonUser.Domain + "/" + computerName,logonUser.Domain + "\\" + logonUser.UserID,logonUser.Password))
        {
            //get local admin group

            using (DirectoryEntry group = machine.Children.Find("Administrators","group"))
            {
                //get all members of local admin group
                object members = group.Invoke("Members", null);

                foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)members)
                {
                    //get account name
                    string accountName = new DirectoryEntry(member).Name;
                    bool isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(accountName);
                    if (isAdmin == true) { admin = true; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return admin;
}
```

However, across domain, this simply comes back with 'network path not found'.
I have been experimenting with LDAP but not getting too far. I have tried a number of methods and ideally need an example. This is what I am using currently:

```
        String strPath = "LDAP://172.24.242.51/CN=258TP520,OU=258,DC=net,DC=test,DC=co,DC=uk";
        DirectoryEntry myDE = new DirectoryEntry(strPath, "testdom\user", "password");
        List<string> memberof = new List<string>();
        foreach (object oMember in myDE.Properties["memberOf"])
        {
            memberof.Add(oMember.ToString());
        }
```

However myDE.properties doesn't seem to contain anything. All help appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed to append the FQDN to the computername, like so

```
using (DirectoryEntry machine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://"  + computerName + ".net.test.co.uk",logonUser.Domain + "\\" + logonUser.UserID,logonUser.Password))
```

This fixed my issue.